# Define custom callbacks on ruby method

Tags: ruby, callback, metaprogramming, observer-pattern

I have many service classes with `call` method having variation in arguments.

I want to call a function `notify` at the end of each `call` method. I don't want to modify those service classes but I am open to modify base class.

I am playing with `ActiveSupport::Callbacks` but it doesn't serve the purpose of not modifying service class.

```
require 'active_support'
class Base
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  define_callbacks :notifier

  set_callback :notifier, :after do |object|
    notify()
  end

  def notify
    puts "notified successfully"
  end
end

class NewPost < Base
  def call
    puts "Creating new post on WordPress"
    # run_callbacks :notifier do
    #   puts "notifying....."
    # end
  end
end

class EditPost < Base
  def call
    puts "Editing the post on WordPress"
    # run_callbacks :notifier do
    #   puts "notified successfully"
    # end
  end
end

person = NewPost.new
person.call
```

**Problem** In order to run callbacks, I need to uncomment the commented code. But here you can see that I need to modify existing classes to add `run_callbacks` block. But that is not what I want. I can easily call `notify` method instead without adding such complexity.

Can anybody suggest how can I get to the solution ruby way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
require 'active_support'
class Base
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  define_callbacks :notifier

  set_callback :notifier, :after do |object|
    notify()
  end

  def notify
    puts "notified successfully"
  end

  def call
    run_callbacks :notifier do
      do_call
    end
  end

  def do_call
    raise 'this should be implemented in children classes'
  end
end

class NewPost < Base
  def do_call
    puts "Creating new post on WordPress"
  end
end

person = NewPost.new
person.call
```

Another solution without ActiveSupport:

```
module Notifier
  def call
    super
    puts "notified successfully"
  end
end


class NewPost
  prepend Notifier

  def call
    puts "Creating new post on WordPress"
  end
end

NewPost.new.call
```

You should check your ruby version `prepend` is a "new" method (2.0)

Comment: Looks good but again it doesn't serve the purpose. I don't want to change all the children classes. Additionally, the solution you suggest would required to change all the references to `call` method as well.

Comment: This is the way ActiveSupport::Callbacks is used in Rails... You can also prepend a notifier module (see edited answer)

Comment: Awsome. I love second solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally the callbacks are set in the inheriting classes. Not sure what you want to achieve from your example, but from your initial description it should be this:

```
require 'active_support'

class Base
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  define_callbacks :call

  def call
    run_callbacks(:call) { puts "something is happening..." }
  end
end

class Post < Base
  set_callback :notify, :after, :call

  private

  def notify
    puts "new post!"
  end
end

post = Post.new
post.call
```